# Scrolling issues with website. Using ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am generating components with ReactJS that get rendered as a webpage - great all working so far. However, If I render elements outside of the screen I am unable to scroll to them.

The only way I can see the elements outside of the screen is if I zoom out. why is this? Does anyone know How to change this?

Everything I search in google is either about a scroll event or a none ReactJS environment.

I have many css files, but the index.css (which is automatically generated my create-react-app) looks like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;


}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

Comment: Lookup over the css files if there's anything like `overflow: hidden` or `overflow-y: hidden`

Comment: I have changed overflow in some css files, but none are loaded with this page and when I remove them, the scroll bars just go back to default on the specific elements on the other pages. I tried overflow: scroll; on the body, but this just provides the bars and no slider and I am still unable to scroll.

Comment: Does the container in which you are rendering these off-screen elements have a height set?